# using loops to print images/patterns in java

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

Write class LoopPractice. This class MUST use loops to printout the following
picture. Write the code in the main method.
First Picture:

```
/

\\

///

\\\\

/////

\\\\\\

///////
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
for(int a=1; a<=7; a=a+2){  
    for(int i=1; i<=a; i++)
        System.out.print("/");
    System.out.println(" ");
    for(int c=0; c<a; c=c+2)
        System.out.print("\\\\");
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

But it is printing a line of 8"\" at the end. Shouldn't the loop be terminated before that can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're just starting to study programming, so here is the code for you:

```
public class LoopPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int counter = 0; counter<7; counter++){

            for(int times=0;times<=counter;times++){

                if(counter%2==0){

                    System.out.print("/");

                }else{

                    System.out.print("\\");

                }
            }

            System.out.println();           
        }
    }

}
```

chenchuk's code is better, though I'm not sure if you know about the ternary operator. if not, you may want to read [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (int j=1 ; j<8 ; j++){
    for(int k=0 ; k<j ; k++){
        // checking if row number is Even/Odd to print '\' or '/'
        System.out.print((j%2 == 0)? "\\" : "/");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```